# An online project managment software

Tags: project-management

I am searching for a good online project managment software. There are plenty of them though. So, the best way would be to get some recommendations. :-)

Lately I've found Zoho Projects.. does anyone use it?

Thanks for answers.

Andy

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/723/online-project-management-services  
Seriously though, the "Similar" button in google search results is actually quite good.

Answer (score 2):

I've used ProjectPier: http://www.projectpier.org/
but we are now moving to http://teambox.com/community

They are open source "replicas" of Basecamp.  Teambox seems to be much more up to date as ProjectPier hasn't had a release in a loooooooooooong time.

There's also Trac, which I like because it ties into svn and gives you milestones, bug tracking, etc. http://trac.edgewall.org/

Comment: I should note that these 3 are all open source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [AgileZen](http://agilezen.com/) and I'm happy with it. It implements the Kanban methodology and its very simple and effective. Pricing is not cheap, but they give a free account to free software projects.